# Installing a GRUB theme causes ubuntu not to boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, themes

bit of an ubuntu newbie here so bare with me.

I'm running a dual boot setup, on an XPS-13-9370 laptop, standard ubuntu.

Previously, I had a grub theme installed from gnome-look.org, and it was working fine, looked great. The other day I started up and got to grub2 menu perfectly fine. However, selecting ubuntu just results in a black screen. Windows boots fine.

I purged and reinstalled grub, and ubuntu would boot again. I thought it might be an issue with that particular theme, so I installed a different one, and that resulted in the black screen again.

It's not a super huge deal as I can just not use a theme, but they did look very nice. Anyone run into this before?

Comment: please, list here the steps you do to install a new theme. Do you use grub customizer or edit grub?

Comment: The first time I saw the issue I used grub customizer. The second time the theme came packaged with it's own .sh script, which also caused the issue

Comment: Hello. What is standard ubuntu? An actual version number is required to help with the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is helpfull:
How to install a grub theme:

Extract the theme to /boot/grub/themes/

Edit `/etc/default/grub file`. Find the line starting with "#GRUB_THEME" and change it to "GRUB_THEME=/boot/grub/themes/[THEME_FOLDER]/[theme.txt]" (replace [THEME_FOLDER] ; [theme.txt] ; remove "[]" brackets)

Run `sudo update-grub`. Before editing make backup!

See also: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Unified_Bootloader and/or
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB